# How to override default font with virtual font

Tags: fonts, font-metrics

My setup: TL 2014 (packaged with Debian 8)

I'm trying to create a virtual font and override original font with it. The idea is to copy necessary files of original font with prefix 'o' and in virtual font refer to that.

All the files will be tested in current directory:

```
mkdir mydir && cd mydir
```

Copy the default font to be overriden:

```
cp `kpsewhich cmr10.tfm` ocmr10.tfm
```

Create virtual font (replace `M` to `i`):

```
tftopl cmr10 > cmr10.vpl
patch cmr10.vpl << EOF
0a1
> (MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME ocmr10))
564a566
>    (MAP (SETCHAR C i))
EOF
vptovf cmr10.vpl
```

Create test file and compile it:

```
echo "\font\tenrm=cmr10 \tenrm M \bye" > test.tex
tex test.tex
```

Now if we run `dvipdfmx test.dvi` and then view resulting pdf document, everything is processed without errors, but the document contains original symbol (i.e., as if no virtual font was used). If we open dvi file via `xdvi test.dvi` directly instead, the correct symbol is printed, but the following warnings are produced:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ocmr10
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ocmr10.
mktexpk: perhaps ocmr10 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

What should be done to override a default font with virtual font so that it will be processed by all programs?

Comment: At the end you want a real glyph, not a virtual one. So your virtual font shouldn't be the end of the line. Create a virtual font `ocmr10.vpl` which gets its glyphs from the real cmr10, and then use it as `\font\tenrm=ocmr10 \tenrm ...`

Comment: That's the point. I need that virtual font has the same name as original font (i.e., in cmr10.vpl I refer to original font, which must of course be renamed, and in my document I need to be able to refer simply to cmr10). Yes, this is not trivial. I hope someone can recommend a solution.

Comment: Don't do it. You would have to change the original cmr10.tfm and it is really a very bad idea to have manipulated versions of this files. It would break all your other documents. I also don't see any reason to do it. If you are able to change core files like the standard fonts you should also be able to change the font definitions in a document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wouldn't like to distract from the main topic. Do you know how to move this discussion to the chat?

Comment: Please don't be offended by this question: no offence is intended. Have you ever created the support files necessary to get an arbitrary type1 font to work with (pdf)LaTeX? That is, have you done this in a case where you are not dealing with the additional complication of wanting to combine characters from different fonts, but where you are just creating the files necessary to use a bog standard font correctly?

Comment: @cfr No, I have never created support files for (pdf)LaTeX. Regarding my initial question, I'm almost there - I figured out the issue with xdvi just now (later I will write it in the post). The only thing now which is left to do so that everything will work as I intended, is this: **replace** `cmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb` in default map file with `ocmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb`. Do you know how to do this correctly?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko You mustn't **replace** that line. You could **add** that line for your local installation. To do that for TeX Live, put it in a file with the extension`.map` e.g. `ocmr.map` or whatever. Then install that map file into TEXMFLOCAL. Probably `<TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/map/dvips/ocmr/>` would be the right place. Then add `Map ocmr.map` to `<TEXMFLOCAL>/web2c/updmap.cfg`, creating it if necessary. Now update the filename database and then run `updmap-sys`.

Comment: @cfr And how to delete `cmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb` from default map? Also, is it possible to edit system file directly without creating local files?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Sorry but I am not going to answer those questions. If you want to render your TeX installation useless, that's your prerogative. But I am not going to help you. If you really want to do it, you can figure out how and then the chances are you'll be able to *undo* it as well. But, if you do that, your changes will be almost certainly be overwritten when you update your installation. There is no way to protect changes made to the system files in the main tree from being overwritten on update. That's why `updmap` works as it does and why TEXMFLOCAL exists.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I do not recommend changing the metrics of standard font files, especially not on system level. Using a new font name and configuring the TeX file/package/... to use the new font name instead seems the cleaner approach to me.

---

In the virtual font, `ocmr10.tfm` is referred. But only the metrics exists.
An actual font mapping is needed, but you cannot use the original font `cmr10`, because you have overwritten the `cmr10.tfm` file with the patched virtual version.

When pdfTeX in PDF mode is used, the mapping from `ocmr10.tfm` to the Type 1 version is easy:

```
 \pdfmapline{+ocmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb}
```

In other cases, a map file `ocmr.map` is needed with contents

```
ocmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb
```

TeX do not yet need the map file, because it only uses the VF and TFM files, but the drivers has to be configured to use the map file.
But each driver, you want to use, has to be configured accordingly to use the `.map` file.

Alternatively the map file can be managed via `updmap`, but this works on the whole TeX system.

Another point is that there are *two* different `cmr10.tfm`. thus the search paths for TeX and drivers has to be configured, that the right version is found first.

### `dvips`

Setting up the font for `dvips` is quite complex.

The map file cannot be directly be given on the command line, instead the map file is specified via a configuration file `config.ocmr`:

```
    p -deletecm.map
    p +ocm.map
```

The file file `deletecm.map` contains the old entry for `cmr10`:

```
cmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb
```

(For experiments I had used "p -cm.map", which excludes all CM fonts).
This mapping for `cmr10` must be removed, otherwise the virtual font is not looked up and the PFB font file is used directly.

The configuration file is not found in the current directly, thus
the call for dvips needs a changed environment variable `TEXCONFIG`, which includes the current directory:

```
TEXCONFIG=:. dvips -P ocmr test
```

Or you can create a TDS tree, e.g. `./texmf.home`, where the files are put into the correct subdirectories. Then the programs are called with `TEXMFHOME` pointing to this TDS tree:

```
TEXMFHOME=./texmf.home tex test
TEXMFHOME=./texmf.home dvips -P ocmr test
```

Comment: I don't think that creating a map is enough. If I got the description right then imho the wrong metrics are still used.

Comment: It seems there is a typo: *ocrm10* (should be ocmr10?). Could you recommend how to use the map in dvips or dvipdfmx? `dvips -u+ocmr.map` does not work. To answer for what it is needed - I'm just curious, and think that it's interesting problem which will help me to better understand the basis.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: Then I suggest that you try to exchange M and i -- to make sure that you get also the metrics right. With A and B you will not see if you get them wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed the example. How do you suggest to check the metrics?

Comment: Well type some text with M and i and look if they occupy the correct space.

Comment: I realized that maybe it is possible to remap only with encoding file and we don't need virtual font at all - is it possible to create such an encoding file that it will take selective symbols of the font from another location in the glyph container (possibly even from another glyph container)?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko You can't combine glyphs from different fonts just using an encoding, as far as I know. You can use an encoding file to say which characters belong in which slots.

Comment: Why does pdfTeX even use the `ocmr10...` line if what's requested in the document is `cmr10`? I guess I'm too used to LaTeX's font definition files...

Comment: @cfr Because default cmr10 was overriden by virtual font with the same name (which now references ocmr10, which is former cmr10).

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Oh, right. I forgot that bit. It isn't really a virtual font, though. There is no `.vf`, is there?

Comment: @cfr Yes, there is. See the new answer.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko No, there's not. That is not done simply with an encoding. You are using a virtual font. (Well, sort of. It is a little confused actually.)

Answer (score 2):

In the case of dvipdfmx, it seems that cmr10.vf is
not read if the original map is effective.
The follwoing gives an output which Igor wants:

```
\special{pdf:mapline -cmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb}
\special{pdf:mapline +ocmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb}
\nopagenumbers
\font\xxx=cmr10
\xxx M
\bye
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works.
See **EDIT** - you are right about vf-file. Please change `\xxx A` to `\xxx M` because I changed the initial example, as Ulrike Fischer suggested.
The question remains why xdvi shows warnings and how to fix them?

Comment: I realized that maybe it is possible to remap only with encoding file and we don't need virtual font at all - is it possible to create such an encoding file that it will take selectve symbols of the font from another location in the glyph container (possibly even from another glyph container)? And how to activate such encoding file system wide, not with `\special` commands?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: You can exchange glyphs (from the same real font) with encoding files, but not the metrics. TeX will place the glyphs and do the line breaking with the information from the tfm file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unless you also create a suitable `.tfm`, of course. I'm not entirely sure what is known at this point....

Answer (score 2):

A bit long as a comment so I'm adding this as answer. As it looks as if you don't take the font metrics into account here an example to show you that you can't simply exchange glyphs.

The following document uses only one "real" font: `sftt1000.pfb`. The first paragraph sets this font using the metrics from the normal roman family and the second the correct metrics from the tt-font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%replace the real font, needs pdflatex:
\pdfmapline{=ecrm1000 SFRM1000 " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t1.enc <sftt1000.pfb}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\ttfamily   
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you recommend any description of the whole encoding map specification? This topic is quite interesting to me. Actually, I'm interested if I can compose a separate tfm file and then fill it with glyphs from different font containers (say, slots 0--127 from the default, and slots 128--255 from the other). I'm going to use a manually crafted tfm which will correspond to the substituted glyphs.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko You need to use a virtual font if you want to combine glyphs from different fonts into a single TeX font (i.e. a single `.tfm`). This is what the virtual font mechanism was invented for, as I understand it. It made it possible to use, for example, the fi/fl/etc. ligatures supplied with type1 postscript fonts, even though these were typically in a different `.pfb` from the regular, lowercase glyphs.

Answer (score -2):

**WARNING**
This brings incompatibilities into your TeX installation. Do this only if you understand what you are doing.

---

Thanks to everyone! With the help of your answers I obtained the solution. Just to sum it up, here are all the steps:

All the files will be tested in current directory:

```
mkdir mydir && cd mydir
```

Copy the default font to be overriden:

```
cp `kpsewhich cmr10.tfm` ocmr10.tfm
```

Create virtual font (replace A to B):

*NOTE* this is example serves simply to demonstrate the basic principles, we assume that metrics in the tfm file already corresponds to the new glyphs (in the real case it will be properly created virtual font which combines several "physical" fonts in it).

```
tftopl cmr10 > cmr10.vpl
patch cmr10.vpl << EOF
0a1
> (MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME ocmr10))
482a4845
>    (MAP (SETCHAR C B))
EOF
vptovf cmr10.vpl
```

Now we have `vf` and `tfm` files for `cmr10`:

```
$ ls
cmr10.vf cmr10.tfm cmr10.vpl ocmr10.tfm
```

Create test file and compile it:

*NOTE* the `\font\tenrm=cmr10 \tenrm` part will not be needed when we rebuild the format, it is here only to simplify the example

```
echo "\font\tenrm=cmr10 \tenrm A \bye" > test.tex
tex test.tex
```

For `xdvi`, copy former `pk` for new `ocmr10`:

```
cp `kpsewhich cmr10.pk` ocmr10.600pk
```

(If there is no `pk`-file for a given font, copy `mf`-file instead)

For `dvipdfmx`, map file must be changed. In my case, I don't need system tree to be protected from updates, so I simply change pdftex.map:

```
sudo perl -i -pe 's/^cmr10/ocmr10/' `kpsewhich pdftex.map`
```

Now check that everything works:

```
$ xdvi test.dvi
$ dvipdfmx test.dvi
< view pdf file >
```

Comment: Please add a warning telling people not to do this at home! Seriously, this should have a large warning on it. It just really ought not be done at all but, if it is, it should be done only by consenting adults in the privacy of their own homes. There may be children reading this page!